# Want to import data from old database(mysql) to new database(mysql) in kettle

Tags: kettle

Hi i have a scenerio i have a database dump which i want to import in my new rails web applications database i have used activerecord etl gem but now the demand is that use kettle etl for importing the data. i have no idea of kettle can someone help me or link me the tutorials from where by following it i can do my job?
thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it's very easy. Just use Table Input to read from current MySQL Table, do some transformation, pipe it to Table Output. In the Table Output, point it to target MySQL connection, fill in the table name and click "Generate SQL" button to execute the DML generated.

For example you can see my article for a sample Excel to MySQL, but the operation can easily converted for MysQL-MySQL migration. (The site is in Indonesian - you can translate it using Google Translator)

http://pentaho.phi-integration.com/kettle/export-excel-ke-mysql

Comment: thanks for your answer, by the way i have also sorted it out :)